# How to fix "Permission denied to access property 'document'"?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver

While trying to automate testing with selenium rc I ran into this problem. I was just following the steps in the tutorials. Here is the code (same as tutorials):

```
[TestFixture]
public class SeleniumTest
{
    private ISelenium selenium;
    private StringBuilder verificationErrors;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, @"*custom D:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox 4\firefox.exe", "http://www.google.com/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }

    [Test]
    public void TheGoogleTest()
    {
        selenium.Open("/");
        selenium.Type("lst-ib", "selenium");
        try
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(selenium.IsTextPresent("Selenium - Web Browser Automation"));
        }
        catch (AssertionException e)
        {
            verificationErrors.Append(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the test, my firefox-5 browser pops up and the url looks like this:
*http://www.google.com/selenium-server/core/RemoteRunner.html?sessionId=507c2d6ec7214587984f0f86148e9ff5&multiWindow=true&baseUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&debugMode=false*

I thought the url should be *http://localhost:4444* and changed the url (leaving the rest). Now a selenium page opens up (with commands on the right). It then opens the google page, but nothing after that. And nunit shows me the test case failed, stating the reason: *Permission denied to access property 'document'*

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommend this be moved to the software automation and testing exchange site

Comment: Should I link my account to sqa.stackexchange.com and repost? Or, can I somehow link this question to there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered it on [sqa.stackexchange.com](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/how-to-fix-permission-denied-to-access-property-document):

I tried with `"*chrome D:\Program Files (x86)\Firefox 4\firefox.exe"` and seems it is working.

Quote from the link mentioned:

> Here `*chrome` refers to firefox browser and has elevated security
>   privileges on java script security restrictions.