# FirefoxDriver and Selenium WebDriver (C# / NuGet) - trying to bypass Javascript security errors

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I found [How to fix “Permission denied to access property 'document'”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742271/how-to-fix-permission-denied-to-access-property-document) and [How to fix “Permission denied to access property 'document'”?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1453/how-to-fix-permission-denied-to-access-property-document) but none of those help directly as I don't know where to stick the `*chrome` they all talk about. Supposedly this should launch Firefox with a [special profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569977/list-of-selenium-rc-browser-launchers) with elevated security privileges, to bypass Javascript security errors. Why do I need this? Well, I am trying to understand when all (or selected) IFRAMEs load completely [just like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4548984/detect-if-the-iframe-content-has-loaded-successfully). But due to security I cannot access the document of an IFRAME. So I want to use Firefox with special privileges to overcome the imposed security limitations.

So with the simple code as below, where and how do I apply `*chrome` thing?

```
var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

// Do something with profile...

using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile))
{
}
```

Comment: So when are you seeing this error? Where is it thrown? (What line?) Does Firefox open?

Comment: I have edited the question to include more context. Basically, I am trying to access IFRAME's document and I can't. So I am looking for ways to overcome this. To answer your question more directly, I get exception when I try to execute JavaScript within the context of an IFRAME.

Comment: You're confusing Selenium RC (`*chrome`) with Selenium WebDriver. Trying to chase down "where... to apply the `*chrome` thing" is a red herring.

Comment: I am new to all this so you probably have a point in the *confusing* part. Still, looks related and I was hoping to get a positive response. Are you saying it's impossible?